# What is the effect of removing script tags after page load (jquery sortable bug)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, cross-browser, jquery-ui-sortable

I am unable to apply sortable constructively [because of inline script tags](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/10901) within sortable items. Following solution is working if I remove script tags on start event e.g

```
$('.sortable').sortable({
  items:" > li:visible",
  start:function(event,ui){
       $(this).addClass('sorting');
       $(this).find('script').remove()
      }
})
```

My question is , what will be the effect of `$(this).find('script').remove()`
 across the browsers (after page load) ?

Although this solution is working but I am not sure of any pitfalls.

Answer (score 0):

JQuery's method `.remove()` is similar to `.empty()` method which takes elements out of the DOM. As soon as you fire `$(this).find('script').remove()` all select elements are gone - check your html with your browser's element inspector!

You should also know, that JQuery supports all modern browsers including old browsers like Internet Explorer 7. If you encounter an issue with a browser using jQuery, you should submit a bug report. JQuery is a framework and the big advantage of frameworks is their compatibility.

cheers.

Comment: thanks @Alex , my question was the effects of removing the script tags on the functionality of application.